# Why do both of these C statements produce same outputs

Tags: c, xcode, syntax, binary, equation

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
     int x = 0x80000000;
     printf("%i\n",(((x - 1) >> 31) & 1));  //shows 0 as output
     printf("%i\n",!(((x - 1) >> 31) & 1));  //shows 0 as output(expected 1)
}
```

Why is this happening? As both the statements perform the same operation except the ! operator. Why do the second printf not give 1 as output?
From what I know a logical not over 0 gives 1 and logical not over other numbers gives 0. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you guarantee that variable `x` will never be negative, you can use `unsigned int` instead of `int`. So `x` will not be out of boundary of `int` and you avoid _undefined behaviour_ explained in @bush's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a manifestation of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) caused by signed integer overflow.

Assuming a 32-byte `int` using two's complement, the value 0x80000000 is outside the range of `int`, so it undergoes an implementation-defined conversion.  Most likely, it converts to the value -2147483648 which is the minimum value that can be held in a `int` on your system.

The next thing you do in both cases is subtract 1 from this value.  This is *not* guaranteed to wrap around.  This is considered overflow and is undefined behavior.  This is why you see the results you're seeing.  Once you have undefined behavior, there are no guarantees what the program will do.